# Backup Laptops/Desktops To Server Fast/Simply

Tags: backup, desktop, laptop, images

Is there anyway to backup various laptops/desktops connected through my network to my server.

I can put any kind of operating system on this server.  I was thinking maybe there is some type of clonezilla that will work for this task.  So yes I do want images of the machines.

I'm guessing it would have to have DHCP, PXE capabilities, etc...

Any suggestions?

Pretty much I just want to stop using my external drive and have to do machines one at a time to back them up and instead back up several all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/). It can pull the backups on many protocols like rsync,  SMB, nfs, ... It has a good web interface. It's easy to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Or [UrBackup](http://urbackup.org/). It can do image backups of Windows clients. You can do that while they are running so you do not need an PXE environment.

You did not say which operating systems your clients have?

Comment: I'm sorry they are windows clients usual 7 and vista

Comment: I'm looking into this and there are a few things that I do not like

-a client on the computer that you want to backup is required
-due to the client being required there is no way an actual complete image can be backed up (files in use, hidden files, etc...) This is highlighted by the fact it cannot backup Outlook pst files

Comment: Windows has the capability of backing up volumes even if they are used. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy
Of course you can also use something like [Clonzilla](http://clonezilla.org/) but it's not necessary anymore

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Crashplan... you can designate one device in your network as a target for the backups from other machines. With user level restore capability. Then backup the datastores.